# Dachshund Head Swelling

Tags: dogs, dachshunds

## Update

Sammy received the medication well for the last few hours of his life, until he took a turn for the worst. While driving him to the vet, he has passed away and went on his way home. For anyone reading this, I regret to inform you of this sad news.

---

Our doxie senior (11 years old), Sammy, all of a sudden has tremendous swelling among both eyes and forehead. This started two days ago when the underside of his right eye started to swell. At the time we thought of nothing much of it as he always chases small insects like bees around that would sting him, but now looking back I am not so sure. I guess call it bad observations or being a bad owner, but normally if a "bee" would sting him his right under would always bee the areas to swell up. I never correlated that it happening more frequently was a warning sign. Upon checking the area for any bites or string areas I could not find anything. This swelling also has seemed to affect his barking and eating habits. Before the swelling started, he would always bark at every little thing. TRUST ME WHEN I SAY EVERY LITTLE THING. Now when he barks it sounds like it is labored and hurts him to do it! It also caused him in general to stop eating and barking, leading me into thinking that whatever this is, is also hurting his jaw.

Warning: The following picture is of my dog and may contain unsuitable content to some audiences. Viewer's discretion is advised. Please hover over the yellow block to see.

> [image]

My family and I plan on taking him to the vet immediately first thing in the morning. Any help before hand as to what this may be or caused by would be tremendous! If any questions arise, I will be relentlessly checking this post, so please comment and I will update the question.

## Update

Upon helping him down the stairs outside to go use the restroom, he seems very disoriented and dragging his left front leg. He stumbles around and often falls over. He is also having a hard time using the restroom.

Comment: Im no vet but it looks like he needs emergency attention. Get off the internet and take him to an emergency clinic right away.

Comment: Please **take your dog to a vet immediately** or he may die. Let us know how he goes.

Comment: go to the vet right now!!!

Comment: It could be a stroke

Comment: @Paparazzi i have sort of mentioned this in the answer as other tings,but this is just as important to get treated fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your dog has an allergic reaction probably after a snake bite or an insect bite.get it to a vet right now.

this is not the only answer to what it might be but the other things it might be will also need immidiate help from a vet.

**your dog is in danger get it to a vet right now.**

Comment: Turned out to be a severe allergic reaction to a bee sting. Sorry for not responding until now, the vet was keeping him overnight, and by the time I drove back home I was exhausted from the worrying! The vet informed me that the swelling has started to go down and he is more himself.

Comment: Sorry to add a comment on such a heavy note, while Sammy was having very positive results to the medication, he made a turn for the worst. Upon driving him back to the vet for help, he passed away. Thank you for your concern!

Comment: @ChristopherK that was realy sad to hear,it is allways hard to lose a pet but by asking this question here you might have saved other pets,it probably dont help you in your sadness right now but i am realy sorry for your loss.