# My dachshund is 3 months her face is swelling?

Tags: dogs, health

My dachshund is 3 months the Friday night her left cheek swelled up then went down shortly after but it left a ball the vet said it wasn’t anything to worry about, it’s starting to concern me because the right side is doing the same thing. The ball is starting to look like it’s coming out of the skin. If anyone knows please help.[image]

Comment: any swelling of the face or nose of your dog needs to be looked at by your vet as it might be an allergic reaction that can be very serious,we have had this question before and in that case it ended badly.https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17485/dachshund-head-swelling

Comment: "Nothing to worry about" is not a valid diagnosis. The vet should at least tell you what they think this is. A swollen muscle may indeed be "nothing to worry about", but at least you know what it is. And this looks like some swelling in the skin, so it could be an abscess from a rotten tooth or a tumor (there are benign skin tumors, don't panic). **I suggest getting a second opinion from a different vet** or at least getting more information from the first vet.